# Tkinter Get Text entry in Notebook page

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a notebook and added a frame to it:

```
nb = ttk.Notebook(root, style="TNotebook")

page1 = ttk.Frame(nb, style='Frame1.TFrame')
layout1(page1)

nb.add(page1, text='Welcome')
```

So i have a function layout1, the first page of the notebook,
i added to it a Text:

```
def layout1(page):
    
    entry = Text(page, width=20)
    entry.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.1, height=400)
    Button(page, text='EXECUTE', command=import_entry).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6)
```

And next i have my import_entry function:

```
def import_entry():
    result = entry.get()
    print(result)
```

I can't get the entry because of accessibilty of variables in function. So, how can i get it?

Comment: You would either use global variables, but that is very bad practice, and you shouldn't do it. Or you would write your application as a class. Then you define all your widgets as class attributes with self. and then you can access them from every method of your class.

Comment: thanks, I think i will use class then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you should structure your app with a class:

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # assign on_closing method to window close event
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

        self.title("Example App")
        self.geometry("600x500")

        self.button_1 = tkinter.Button(master=self, text="Test", command=self.button_event)
        self.button_1.pack(pady=10)

        # create more widgets ...

    def button_event(self, event):
        print("button pressed")

    def on_closing(self):
        # code that needs to happen when gets closed

        self.destroy()  # controlled closing of window with .destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```